# Task 'server' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I got an error while running [JAMstack](https://github.com/jamstack/jamstack.org#usage):

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.19.1
$ gulp server
[05:04:13] Using gulpfile /jamstack.org/gulpfile.js
[05:04:13] Task 'server' is not in your gulpfile
[05:04:13] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you recieve?

Comment: When I run "yarn start" command in terminal to run the project it gives me that error that I sent earlier.